# Opening a file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, compiler-errors

I am trying to open a file stored on my c drive with name `test.txt`.I am getting a lot of errors.I am new to filing in C++.Please help me out thanks.
// writing on a text file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std; 
int main ()
 {
    ofstream mystream;
    mystream.open("C:\\test",ios::in||ios::out);
        /*Check if the file is opened properly*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the errors you are getting?

Comment: ofstream is an output filestream, for writing to the file, you might want to check out ifstream.

Comment: @Captain - would you like to rephrase?

Comment: Is this a compile error or a run-time error?

Comment: No, it is ok. As long as you specify `ios::in|ios::out` for open, it will behave as an fstream. ifstream and ofstream just have default open modes, but you can override that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
mystream.open("C:\\test",ios::in || ios::out);
```

should be

```
mystream.open("C:\\test",ios::in | ios::out);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the logical OR operator (`||`) instead of the bitwise OR operator (`|`). The former returns a boolean value, while the latter returns the bitwise OR of the two values.

Answer (score 2):

You probably also want to fully qualify the filename.  For example:

```
mystream.open("C:\\test.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
```